# Building Windows Docker images: Lambda-EC2 vs Docker Hub vs AWS ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerhub, docker-for-windows, amazon-ecr

### Problem

The problem is CodeBuild can not build windows Docker image. That happens due to the fact that CodeBuild is runing inside Docker container, and Microsoft does not support Docker inside Docker.

I know, not the first question about this topic, i.e. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49785539/building-windows-containers-with-aws-codebuild). But I gonna suppose some alternatives to the standard workflow that looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49785539/building-windows-containers-with-aws-codebuild/50574301#50574301).

**Important:** As I understand, Windows Docker image of Microsoft Server 2016 can be built only from Microsoft Server 2016 system/container.

### Standard approach

1. CodeBuild triggers Lambda
2. Lambda launches image of EC2 with Docker
3. EC2 instance pulls source code, build image from Dockerfile, push image to repo & trigger CodePipeline.
4. CodePipeline deploys image

### Quetions

Instead of implementing custom image-build step, we can use one of 3rd party solutions: Docker Hub or AWS ECR.

1. Is AWS ECR able to build Docker images from Docker file? Is it possible to make builds on Microsoft Server 2016 system/container?
2. Is Docker Hub able to build Docker images on Microsoft Server 2016 system/container?

Comment: Or you can just build in Azure Devops for free with free WIndows build agents and then upload to AWS ECR or Azure ACR

Comment: @GregorySuvalian could you please provide more details? I'm not DevOps, just developer that managing CI/CD.  How could I call Azure Devops from CodePipeline? Does Azure support my requirement about Windows Server 2016? How much confings it will require?

Comment: @GregorySuvalian we are doing DevOps through CloudFormation. As I understand Azure DevOps will require configuring DevOps Pipeline outside of CloudFormation, right?

Comment: Yes, it's hosted and provided by Microsoft

Comment: @GregorySuvalian sorry, not an option for us. Let it be within CoudFormation or require no or minimal configs